# ¿Por qué mi página en React no actualiza la tabla cuando se edita?

Tags: reactjs

Cuando actualizo un valor del campo, este no se actualiza en mi tabla, pero cuando elimino o agrego un registro nuevo, sí lo hace. No sé dónde está fallando; el Backend funciona ya que sí actualiza el valor en la base de datos, pero no se por qué razón no se actualiza la tabla al momento de hacer el cambio.
Acá el fragmento del código de la función que hace el cambio

```
 const editarValidador = async () => {
    await axios.put(URL_API.API_URL + 'validador/EditarValidador' + "/" + validadorSelect.validador_id, validadorSelect)
        .then(response => {
            var dataNueva = data;
            console.log(dataNueva);
            dataNueva.map(validador => {
                if (validador.validador_id == validadorSelect.validador_id) {
                    console.log(validador.validador_id);
                    console.log(validadorSelect.validador_id+" el otro ")
                    validador.tipoValidacion = validadorSelect.tipoValidacion;
                    validador.claseJava = validadorSelect.claseJava;
                    validador.entrada = validadorSelect.entrada;
                }
            });
           
            console.log(dataNueva);
            setData(dataNueva);
            
            openModalEdit();
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
}
```

Uso material Table para la construcción del datatable

```
           <MaterialTable
            columns={columns}
            data={data}

            title="Lista de validadores Disponibles"
            actions={[
                {
                    icon: 'edit',
                    tooltip: 'Editar Validador',
                    onClick: (event, rowData) => validadorSeleccionado(rowData, "Editar")
                },
                {
                    icon: 'delete',
                    tooltip: 'Eliminar Validador',
                    onClick: (event, rowData) => validadorSeleccionado(rowData, "Eliminar")
                }
            ]}
        />
```

Acá llamo al modal

```
  <Modal
                open={modalEdit}
                onClose={openModalEdit}>
                {bodyEditar}
            </Modal>
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Revisa los `;` :-)

Comment: Estaría bien saber que te devuelve la api como respuesta cuando editas un registro y la función validadorSeleccionado, ya que es a esta función a la que llamas cuando editas en la tabla.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba llamando al metodo donde extraes los datos en el usefect para que renderize de nuevo el componente

```
  const EditProduct = async (newRow, sku) => {
    await axios.put(url + '/' + id, newRow).then((response) => {
      const data = response.data
      console.log(data);
      getData()
      swal({
        title:'name',icon:'success',button:'Aceptar',timer:'2000'
      })
      console.log(response.status)
    })
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])
```